# Change DataTables ColVis exclude option on the fly?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to change jQuery DataTables ColVis extension [`exclude`](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/colvis/options) option on the fly?

I have the datatable

```
    $("#calc_tabl").DataTable({
        paging: false,
        colVis: {
            buttonText: "Show/hide",
            //exclude: [0]
        },
        dom: 'C<"clear">frtiS'
    });
```

By clicking the button i want to change excluding columns but I need not to reload whole table.

```
    $("#calc_tabl").DataTable({
        paging: false,
        colVis: {
            buttonText: "Show/hide",
            exclude: [2,3]
        },
        dom: 'C<"clear">frtiS'
    });
```

There is a `fnSettings()` function like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
  alert( oSettings );
} );
```

Maybe it is possible to extract ColVis options from `oSettings`? But there is no "ColVis" or the same parameter.

Comment: what do you mean by `on the fly` ? After drawing datatable , i don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post by Allan Jardine](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/54113/#Comment_54113), creator of jQuery DataTables, changing excluded columns on the fly wasn't possible with ColVis extension.

Alternative option could be to re-initialize your table.